# Complex XML data processing with python

Tags: python, xml

I have this complex xml where the columns are defined in `tbd:ColDef`. In the `tbd:RepBodyRow`, the values are populated without tags. We are receiving this from upstream and load the data using python.

I am expecting the below result:

```
Place         |Parent    |Type 
USA           |USA       |Country 
New York      |USA       |State
NYC           |New York  |City
Manhattan     |NYC       |Town....
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tbd:Wrapper xmlns:tbd="abc.com/tbd">
<tbd:Root xmlns:tbd="abc.com/tbd">
<tbd:JobCnxt>
    <tbd:Job Date="2021-07-02" Country="USA" />
</tbd:JobCnxt>
<tbd:JobRep RepName="Country Data">
    <tbd:RepDef>
    <tbd:ColDef name="default">
        <tbd:ColDefData Name="place" Type="string" DisplayName="Place"/>
        <tbd:ColDefData Name="placeType" Type="string" DisplayName="Type"/>
    </tbd:ColDef>
    </tbd:RepDef>
    <tbd:RepBody>
    <tbd:RepBodyGroup GroupTypeName="default" GroupDefName="default" GroupDisplayName="">
        <tbd:RepBodyGroup GroupTypeName="distinct" GroupDefName="place" GroupDisplayName="USA">
        <tbd:RepBodyRow ColDefName="default" IsTotalRow="true">
            <tbd:CellData Value="USA"/>
            <tbd:CellData Value="Country"/>
        </tbd:RepBodyRow>
        <tbd:RepBodyGroup GroupTypeName="distinct" GroupDefName="place" GroupDisplayName="New York">
            <tbd:RepBodyRow ColDefName="default" IsTotalRow="true">
            <tbd:CellData Value="New York"/>
            <tbd:CellData Value="State"/>
            </tbd:RepBodyRow>
            <tbd:RepBodyGroup/>
            <tbd:RepBodyGroup GroupTypeName="distinct" GroupDefName="place" GroupDisplayName="NYC">
            <tbd:RepBodyRow ColDefName="default" IsTotalRow="true">
            <tbd:CellData Value="NYC"/>
            <tbd:CellData Value="City"/>
            </tbd:RepBodyRow>
            <tbd:RepBodyRow ColDefName="default">
            <tbd:CellData Value="Manhattan"/>
            <tbd:CellData Value="Town"/>
            </tbd:RepBodyRow>
            <tbd:RepBodyRow ColDefName="default">
            <tbd:CellData Value="Bronx"/>
            <tbd:CellData Value="Town"/>
            </tbd:RepBodyRow>
            <tbd:RepBodyRow ColDefName="default">
            <tbd:CellData Value="Brooklyn"/>
            <tbd:CellData Value="Town"/>
            </tbd:RepBodyRow>
            <tbd:RepBodyRow ColDefName="default">
            <tbd:CellData Value="Queens"/>
            <tbd:CellData Value="Town"/>
            </tbd:RepBodyRow>
        </tbd:RepBodyGroup>
        </tbd:RepBodyGroup>
    </tbd:RepBodyGroup>
    </tbd:RepBodyGroup>
    </tbd:RepBody>
</tbd:JobRep>
</tbd:Root>
</tbd:Wrapper>
```

Comment: The xml in your question is not well formed. Please edit and fix.

Comment: Can you please add your Python code so we can see what you have attempted and where we can help you?

Comment: Updated XML. I am yet to write python code for this. I see this type of xml for first time. I need some suggestions on how to proceed.

Comment: <tbd:CellData Value="USA"/><tbd:CellData Value="Country"/> Keys for this values are available in tbd:ColDef. How can be link these two? Is it possible to write a xslt?

Comment: @PythonBeginner - You can definitely write an XSLT to transform this data. You can apply the XSLT using lxml. Or you can use XPath in lxml without writing a separate XSLT. Whatever is easier for you and easier for you to maintain.

Comment: In a normal xml, we would have this as <place>USA</place><placeType>Country</placeType>. Here, we have these tags, place and placeType, in separate element. How can we link them?

Comment: Those are just attributes. What are you processing the XML with? ElementTree? lxml? There are a few different ways to get the value of an attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This xml doesn't have the most logical structure, given the relevant geography - and the fact that it uses namespaces doesn't help. But you can get close enough.

As an aside, given the structure, there is no row for `USA` since USA has no parent in this sense (being the top entity). In addition, just FYI and FWIW, Manhattan, for example, is not a `town` in `NYC`, it's a borough...

And with all that said:

```
import pandas as pd
from lxml import etree
data = """your xml above"""
doc = etree.XML(data.encode())
columns = ["Place","Type","Parent"]
rows = []
for pair in doc.xpath('//x:RepBodyGroup/x:RepBodyRow',namespaces=ns)[1:]:
    item = pair.xpath('.//x:CellData/@Value',namespaces=ns) 
    group = pair.xpath('./preceding-sibling::x:RepBodyRow[@IsTotalRow="true"][1]/x:CellData[1]/@Value',namespaces=ns)
    group2 = pair.xpath('../preceding-sibling::x:RepBodyRow[@IsTotalRow="true"][1]/x:CellData[1]/@Value',namespaces=ns)
    item.append(group[0] if len(group)>0 else group2[0])
    rows.append(item)
pd.DataFrame(rows,columns=columns)
```

Output:

```
Place   Type    Parent
0   New York    State   USA
1   NYC     City    New York
2   Manhattan   Town    NYC
3   Bronx   Town    NYC
4   Brooklyn    Town    NYC
5   Queens  Town    NYC
```

Comment: Thanks Jack. This is what exactly what I was looking for. It was really helpful.  Btw, thanks for reminding that Manhattan is a borough!

Comment: @PythonBeginner Ha! It's not your fault - it's the fault of the author of the xml... But half seriously, I don't know what this is being used for, but under certain circumstances the geopolitical distinctions (at least in NYS) between towns, townships, villages, districts, etc. may make a significant difference in the outcome. Anyway, if we're done, please don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: Actually, I am the culprit. Instead of pasting the actual xml, I created this xml. I accepted the answer. Thanks Jack!

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to the answer by @jack-fleeting, but it uses `get()` to get attribute values instead of selecting them directly with xpath.

```py
from lxml import etree
import pandas as pd

tree = etree.parse("input.xml")

ns = {"tbd": "abc.com/tbd"}
cols = ["Place", "Parent", "Type"]
rows = list()

for rbr in tree.xpath(".//tbd:RepBodyGroup/tbd:RepBodyRow", namespaces=ns):
    row = list()

    # Get "Place"
    row.append(rbr.xpath("tbd:CellData[1]", namespaces=ns)[0].get("Value", "N/A"))

    # Get "Parent"
    # There won't always be a preceding sibling RepBodyRow.
    try:
        parent = rbr.xpath("../preceding-sibling::tbd:RepBodyRow/tbd:CellData[1]",
                           namespaces=ns)[0].get("Value", "N/A")
    except IndexError:
        parent = "N/A"
    row.append(parent)

    # Get "Type"
    row.append(rbr.xpath("tbd:CellData[2]", namespaces=ns)[0].get("Value", "N/A"))
    rows.append(row)

print(pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=cols))
```

**printed output**

```
       Place     Parent      Type
0        USA        N/A   Country
1   New York        USA     State
2        NYC   New York      City
3  Manhattan        NYC  Sub City
4   County 1  Manhattan    County
5     City 1  Manhattan      Town
6     City 2  Manhattan      Town
7     City 3  Manhattan      Town
8   County 1  Manhattan    County
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel. This is of great help.